# How do I properly insert this php snippet within html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this php snippet:

```
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

I would like to remove:

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

And instead, insert the **title attribute**, called via php, where currently, the Font-Awesome icon sits -- within the hyperlink.  That way, when a visitor hovers over an item, they will see the title instead of a Font Awesome search icon.

So I've tried:

```
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title_attribute(); ?></a>
</div>
```

And that was not successful for reasons perhaps obvious to php developers.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Any guidance in helping me achieve this properly would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct code, that doesn't duplicate `echo`, should be as follows:

```
<div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

As I've mentioned in my comments, [the_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) and [the_title_attribute()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute) already `echo` content. No need to add another `echo` before each.

You should also (usually) favor `the_title()` over `the_title_attribute()` for the actual display of the title.

Comment: @jeroen, indeed it is. However, if adding `echo` before each of those functions works (but removing them doesn't), that implies that something else is wrong.

Comment: True, but how does copying the OP's exact code answer the question then? I must be missing something here because the voting is all over the place as well...

Comment: Thank you jeroen and rnevius.  I promise I'm not seeing things.  But when I do use rnevius's code, the effect is what I was trying to achieve.  I spent a half hour on this, and I was doing precisely that, and for some reason, it wasn't working ... perhaps because I didn't separate the lines properly?

Comment: @JasonWeber This should not be the reason, but at least, nice code formatting helps you anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php echo the_title_attribute('','',false)?>`

The third parameter is for `echo` by default it is `true`, if you want the function to return the value, set it to `false` as shown above.

From [Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute)

Comment: [@rnevious](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3518452/rnevius) suggested is also similar if you don't want to `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo the_title_attribute();`. You want to actually print it into the html.

Answer (score -1):

you were missing = signs after your `<?`

try:

```
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?= the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?= the_title_attribute(); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `the_permalink()` already `echo`es output, as does `the_title_attribute()`

Comment: Hey thelastshadow.  Your solution did achieve the effect I was looking for.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Александр Фишер, that is what I tried, but it didn't achieve the effect I wanted (it actually broke the code).

Comment: WordPress-Functions starting with "the_" always echo. Writing "<?= " is short for writing "<?php echo " - so this solution is not correct and it just works accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you need to use `echo`:

```
<div class="overlay-content">
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php echo the_title_attribute(); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey David; your solution worked, as did thelastshadow's solution.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Hi rnevius, doesn't it depend on the context? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Comment: That's  different function altogether. `get_permalink()` returns the permalink. `the_permalink()` echoes it.